# Typescript - calling async method in a sequence

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, youtube-api

I am trying to create an angular 2 YouTube player service.
The service should provide two methods:

- **playRange** – Play a given range of the video, and at the end jump to a specific time in the video. Range is an array [start, end, returnTime].
  In order to stop the video at the specified time, I need to use setInterval to check the current position of the video, it make the method asynchronous.
- **playScript** – Play a script, which is an array of ranges. So basically it should play few ranges in a sequence.

The playRange implementation:

```
playRange(range: any) {
    if (this.player) {
      console.log('Playing range:' + range)
      const start: number = +range[0];
      const end: number = +range[1];
      const returnTime: number = range.lenth === 3 ? range[0] : range[2];
      this.player.seekTo(start, true);
      clearInterval(this._rangeTimer);
      if (this.player.getPlayerState() !== YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        this.player.playVideo();
      }
      this._rangeTimer = setInterval(() => {
        const currentTime = this.player.getCurrentTime();
        if (currentTime >= end) {
          this.pause();
          clearInterval(this._rangeTimer);
          this.player.seekTo(returnTime, true);
        }      
      }, 200);
    }
  }
```

How should I implement the playScript so I can iterate a sequence of ranges and play them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're inner logic is supposed to work, but this should give you a good highlevel.  Check it out [here](http://type%20RangeArray%20=%20[number,%20number]%20%7C%20[number,%20number,%20number];%20%20function%20playRange(range:%20RangeArray):%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E((resolve,%20reject)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Do%20whatever%20you%20need%20to%20to%20play%20the%20range.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Whenever%20you%20have%20determined%20that%20the%20range%20has%20finished,%20call%20resolve%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve();%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%7D%20%20async%20function%20playScript(ranges:%20RangeArray[]):Promise%3Cvoid%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20while%20(ranges.length%20%3E%200)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20await%20playRange(ranges.pop());%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D):

```
type RangeArray = [number, number] | [number, number, number];

function playRange(range: RangeArray): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        // Do whatever you need to to play the range.
        // Whenever you have determined that the range has finished, call resolve
        resolve();
    });
}

async function playScript(ranges: RangeArray[]):Promise<void> {
    while (ranges.length > 0) {
        await playRange(ranges.pop());
    }
}
```